# Why is factor acting like this in the Images as planes add on?

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene that is a plane from the *Images as planes* addon bent into a circle, and factor is acting strange in it. [image]

As you can see from the picture, white is above blue, but in the node network there is no white. On top of that, the gradient texture shows that white is above black, meaning that blue should be on top. Im not sure if this is related, but on top of that the invert node turns everything white. I know that the images as planes addon acts weird with materials, but Why is this happening?

Blend file - [image]

Comment: You know, you could simply try turning the mesh upside down using rotation. It should probably look correct, why it is happening? I have no idea but is probably a bug.

Comment: That isn't the only problem. The white should not be there, it should be yellow on the bottom and blue on top, as the node network shows. Anyway, this is just a simple demonstration of the problem. My actual node network is much more complex, so I need the long solution.

Comment: Then can you show the complete node setup?

Comment: Use a color ramp instead.

Comment: Again @brockmann, I cannot use shortcut methods to get around this, something is wrong with the way factor works in the images as planes add-on. I am trying to make the earth that responds to nighttime and glows and has a halo around it, and the fact that factor isn't working is royally messing up my results. If I want to fix this, I need to go for the long method. I assume that some weird setting in images as planes materials is causing this. I'll paste the blend here so you guys can check it out.

Comment: No shortcut... also there is nothing wrong. It's just your "wrong" expectations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bao6Y.jpg

Comment: Thank you, I was just confusing greys and whites.